# The icon conflict between bootstrap and font-awesome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

In my project, first, I use bootstrap icon, but I found bootstrap has less icon, so I want to use font-awesome, but when I import the font-awesome css file, the icon change to font-awesome type.

Because other place just use the bootstrap icon, so I want the icon has already used in my project still be viewed in bootstrap type, the special icon in font-awesome I also want to add it.

**Keep the old icon type and add new font-awesome icon at the same time**, how should I do?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: My Scenario is: for example, in one page it didn't import the bootstrap css and just use the font-awesome css, so it just use the .icon-cart class, but I want to use it in another page which has imported the bootstrap css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of both frameworks using the same class names for their icons.

I believe, for instance that they both use a class of `.icon-cart` but have different images

If would be necessary for you to edit the CSS classes relating to clearly identify which relates to which.

So, you could edit the CSS so that the FontAwesome class is (for example) `.awesome-icon-cart` to distinguish it from the Bootstrap glyphs...and so on.

Comment: Hi, Paulie_D, thanks for your reply, but there are maybe some problems if I change the css class name, for example, in one page it didn't import the bootstrap css and just use the font-awesome css, so it just use the .icon-cart class, but I want to use it in another page which has imported the bootstrap css, so ... Do you have other solutions? thanks in advance!

Comment: You would have to edit your mark-up to ensure comsistency across pages. Always use the same class for the same image.

Comment: ok, thank you, Paulie_D, I have decided to copy the font-awesome css and edit the css!

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome gives you the option to use without bootstrap. I would do that so it is separate to bootstrap and then find the location in font-awesome that specifies the class names and prefix it with fa- or something similar.

Comment: Hi, Rachel Reveley, thanks for your reply, but my question is just I comment to Paulie_D, do you have some ideas for it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that you might want to use both variations of the cart icon? If so then my solution of having font-awesome as a separate resource to bootstrap rather than intertwined would fix this so long as you also edit the font-awesome source files so that it uses a custom prefix.

Then if you wanted the BS cart you would use icon-cart
if you wanted the font-awesome cart you would use fs-icon-cart.